# Vectors in MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, vector

basically I work with some image processing stuff. I've bunch of feature vectors (1X128) of an image frame (say, 75 to 100 per frame). I want to store the vectors in a MySQL database and access it from Java code.

I've seen some suggestions from StackOverflow and other places which recommend to vectors/arrays as a BLOB in MySQL. But I couldn't find any specific command line or Java example to store the vectors.

Could anyone please help me out with some examples?

Thanks in Advance.

P.S.: The vectors are basically double values like: [0.25, 0.11, 0.32, 0.66, ...]